# IE8 disappearing image bug

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer

In IE8 (& maybe others), when I leave my page to go to another tab in IE and then come back to my page's tab, each time the cursor runs over an image it disappears until I refresh the page. I've heard of disappearing image bugs, but I couldn't find anything on this particular case, especially given this isn't a weird pre-IE8 bug. I am using a lightbox, so possibly something to do with javascript?

http://dev.bwmsnow.co.nz/snowboarding

Answer (score 0):

Its actually happening after you mouse out of the drop-down menu, even without switching tabs, and the images show up again when you mouse over the nav bar.

I would try remove one script at a time to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Yisroel. I didn't notice it was due to the nav bar. The fix was to add position:absolute to my css for that menu bar.